# Mandrill Web Hook Delay

Tags: javascript, api, email, events, mandrill

I'm using Mandrill for a project and I've set up a webhook to post events(send, open, and click) on an API I have on a URL. The send event webhook fires immediately after sending an email, but the open event takes 4-5 hours to post to the URL and the click event doesn't fire at all. I'm using a free trial of Mandrill and using a single URL to POST all events. What is the problem? Is there any configuration I need to make? Also, I have used an anchor tag in the email template that I need to track, but click events are never fired.

Comment: I have sent the email to myself and opened it immediately after receiving, but the open event fires only after 4-5 hours